# how to set args.rellinks to noparent in tridion Docs

Tags: tridion-docs

In Tridion docs, I want to change the build to include parameter "args.rellinks=noparent". Where can I make the change?

Comment: Could you please explain bit more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: when you publish  a publication where the publication has opics with parent child relationship, DITA-OT transforms the child topic  to have a parent link appended at the bottom of the page. if I want the parent link not to appear at the bottom I can turn it off by providing the following parameter to DITA-OT args.rellinks=noparent. The question is where do I set that parameter in tridion docs?

Answer (score 1):

I read the question "Where do I set that parameter in tridion docs?"

The answer is: you can't

You need to set it in the DITA-OT, either pass it as a parameter when you call the DITA-OT, or set the property in the pdf plugin of the dita-ot, refer to the DITA-OT documentation.

btw, here's the official documentation for the rel links: 
https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-base.html

**args.rellinks**

Specifies which links to include in the output. The following values are supported:

- none – No links are included.
- all – All links are included.
- noparent – Parent links are not included.
- nofamily – Parent, child, next, and previous links are not included.

**For PDF output, the default value is nofamily. For all other formats, the default value is all.**

I hope it helps