# Where on Tridion Server can I set DITA-OT parameters?

Tags: publishing

Since the DITA-OT used by Publication Manager is configured on a Tridion Docs Server.

In which file on the server can be edited it set the DITA-OT parameters

e.g. args.rellinks?

Any advice appreciated,

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange . Please refer to this link https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20638/how-to-set-args-rellinks-to-noparent-in-tridion-docs and refer to this DITA-OT documentation. https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-base.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your output format configuration and plugins, In this **ishrunditaot.ps1** file you need to pass the DITA-OT parameters.

OOTB **DITA-OT** plugin this file can be find in this location.

```
C:\InfoShare\App\Utilities\DITA-OT\InfoShare\ishrunditaot.ps1
```